# Is there a word to refer to the result of worldbuilding?

Tags: word-request

Worldbuilding means putting details into a fictional world. The result, which is a bunch of details of the said fictional world, don't seem to have a specific word for it, or does it?

How would you refer to it if you can't think of a word?

For example:

> In order to have a really imaginative ___, you need to put a lot of
>   work into your worldbuilding.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, once it's done, you've created a . . . *world*. Just like once you've finished building a building, what's left is a  . . . *building*. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, because saying "detailed world" seems to imply that your fictional world is "objectively less detailed" if you don't detail it.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. Using the word *worldbuilding* doesn't necessitate building a *detailed* world. (Who's to say when it's detailed enough?) But even if it did mean that, that's what you'd be left with: a detailed world.

Comment: Using that wording lead to suggestions that may mislead people and may sound weird. World may seem to be under detailed while being "objectively" detailed in the context of a fictional world.

Comment: Using what wording? I just repeated what you said. ("Detailed world.") I honestly don't know what you're asking. Why is *world* or *detailed world* insufficient? Either of those seem to work within the example sentence you've provided.

Comment: Using world seem to make certain suggestions or implications. It's too vague, and the word world basically subsumes a lot of things. When you say the world is detailed, even when interpreted correctly, you cannot know what part of it is detailed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there's not a snappy word for this. I consulted some examples, and I believe something like "fictional universe" or "fictional world" is the best phrase.

Comment: Problem is that it's not really a universe or world were really talking about, is there a more specific word or phrase?

Comment: Universe in this context is more abstract. For example, one could speak of the "fictional universe of Harry Potter", despite the fact that those stories take place in England. a non-fictional place. If you could provide some more context, I could help think of something more specific.

Answer (score 0):

The most appropriate single word to go in there would be ***setting***. When you're *worldbuilding*, you're coming up with the setting for a story (or game, or whatever) - the context in which the work is *set*.

It needn't be a whole world or a universe. It can be a country. It encompasses the idea of how society is set up (if different from our own), what technology is like, if the laws of nature are different, what different races there are (if any), and so on.